# IIS not serving static or dynamic content

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, windows-server-2012, application-pools

I am trying to load:

> `http://localhost`

and

> `http://localhost/folder/page.html`

and

> `http://localhost/folder/page.php`

and I just get the hour glass showing that it is loading, but nothing is loading!

I am able to see files on my server from a different computer by going to

> \\iisserver\inetpub

only windows authentication and basic are enabled, all others disabled

> defaultapppool

is started and integrated

windows firewall is disabled

i'm using IIS8 running on windows server 2012

What am I doing wrong? I would be most grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work remotely?  from the sounds of it, it's the loopback issue.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861